# SDcard initialization issue using SPI on STM32F303

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, spi, hal

I am trying to initialize SDCard using SPI on STM32F303 when I sent CMD0 command which is (0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x95) and I tried to have a look of the signal that is coming from MOSI on the oscilloscope I saw different signal as shown below. Please note that SPI speed is 281.25kBits/s. any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Here is Part of the code I am using to test this output from MOSI

```
uint8_t cmd0[6]={0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x95};
FATFS_CS_HIGH;
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)0xff, 1, 10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)0xff, 1, 10);
   }

  FATFS_CS_LOW;

while(1){

      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)cmd0[0], 1, 10);

      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)cmd0[1], 1, 10);
      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)cmd0[2], 1, 10);
      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)cmd0[3], 1,10);
      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t *) cmd0[4], 1, 10);
      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)cmd0[5], 1, 10);

    }
```

---

Now I am sending the correct command and I can see it on the scope.However, I don't get 0x01 response(I keep getting 0xff) from SDcard(SanDisk Ultra 40MB/s ...16GB) I am using the following code:

```
FATFS_CS_HIGH;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &dumb, 1, 10);
    while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
}

FATFS_CS_LOW;

HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, cmd0, 6, 10);
while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &dumb, 1, 10);
    while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
}
HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &c, 1, 10);
```

Comment: Can you explain whats supposed to happen for anyone who might have an answer and also include what you have tried to resolve this issue thus far

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

You do not wait the end of the SPI transfers before initiating the next one. You also should not send a buffer byte by byte, you can send the whole buffer in one call.

```c
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, cmd0, 6, 10);
while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
```

---

This part of your code just sends rubbish, apart from the problem that you do not wait before sending next byte:

```c
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)0xff, 1, 10);

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)0xff, 1, 10);
}
```

The second parameter is a pointer to the databuffer. Your code won't send `0xff` but some rubbish located at the `0xff` memory address.

To send `0xff` do the following:

```c
uint8_t value = 0xff
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &value, 1, 10);
while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
```

---

**Update**:

Also lines like this:

```
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)cmd0[0], 1, 10);
```

send rubbish data as well.

This `cmd0[0]` will return the first element of the array (the data) which is `0x40`, then you cast it to `uint8_t*`, and pass it to the `HAL_SPI_Transmit` function as **the pointer to the data buffer**. So the actual data that will be sent is some random value at `0x40` memory location.

The address of a certain byte in your array is `&cmd[0]` for example. Note the `&` operator which returns the address. The correct call is:

```
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &cmd0[0], 1, 10);
while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
```

So I suggest again to send the whole array in one call as I showed it above.

Comment: _Your code won't send 0xff but some rubbish located at the 0xff memory address_ - this main problem.

Comment: Thank you very much Bence Kaulics. I have tried intensively to get it worked but with no success. I thought "HAL_SPI_Transmit" takes care of making sure that a byte is sent completely. Would you recommend any good reference to work with stm32 family? Thanks again.

Comment: There is a downloadable zip at the bottom of the page: http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef3.html which holds STM32F3 HAL examples.

Comment: Kindly look at my edited question Bence Kaulics. Thank you.

Comment: @AbdelraheemAlkuor I will try to have a look on it sometime.